# Как скопировать ссылку без создания мусора для GC?

Tags: c#, классы, link, сборщик-мусора

Есть код:

```
public class A {
    public int a,b,c;
}

public class B {
    public static void func (A var) {
        var.a=1;
        A x = var;
        x.b = 7;
    }
}

static void main () {
    A dat = new A();
    B.func(dat);
}
```

dat присваивают ссылку на свой экземпляр.

Далее dat передается в метод.

Насколько я понимаю, при передаче dat в метод, происходит создание копии ссылки. То есть для GC создается +1 ссылка, которая после выхода из func должна быть удалена. Верно?

Возможно ли запретить создание ссылки / не создавать работу для GC ?

Comment: Параметры методов хранятся в стеке. Как только метод закончился, стек эти параметры освобождает.

Comment: Если в методе скопировать ссылку в переменную x, то она тоже удалится?

Comment: куда скопировать?

Comment: Если хотите управлять памятью и временем жизни объектов вручную, то используйте С/C++.

Comment: "куда скопировать?"
Извините, я немного исправил код в вопросе: A x = var;

"Если хотите управлять памятью и временем жизни объектов вручную, то используйте С/C++" - не могу. среда разработки поддерживает только C#

Comment: переменные `var` и `x` сами по себе будут находиться в стеке и указывать на одно и то же место в куче. После выполнения методов, в куче место все также будет занято объектом, но переменные `var` и `x` будут освобождены.

Comment: `Возможно ли запретить создание ссылки / не создавать работу для GC ?` другими словами, в вашем случае GC задействован только тут `A dat = new A();`.

Comment: Все ясно, большое спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, на здоровье.

Comment: "среда разработки поддерживает только C#" - что это за среда разработки такая?

Comment: "что это за среда разработки такая?" - Unity3D

Comment: Под Unity3D вполне можно писать на C/C++...